# "Association Rules Reduction" or "Reduction of Association Rules"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm writing a post about data mining and I was wondering which one of these titles sound better or more formal:

> Association Rules Reduction

or

> Reduction of Association Rules

Is there any difference or specific situation when I should use one and not another?

Comment: That's not a sentence—it's a title. Titles don't even need to be grammatical. But they are certainly subjective.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonBassford, I changed it to "titles". Any ideas on how I can make it more objective?

Comment: *Personally* (without knowing more) I would use the second version, but add an article: ***The*** *Reduction of Association Rules*. That makes it sound more like a noun phrase. If you want to emphasize an activity, then ***Reducing*** *Association Rules* or even ***How to Reduce*** *Association Rules*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to ELL StackExchange :)

Typically the order in which one puts words changes the emphasis or focus on a particular part of a phrase. Putting any given word first calls more attention it. So, the best way to phrase this depends partly on that. You could even put "Rules" first:

> Rules of Association which are Reduced

But that gets so wordy as to obfuscate the meaning. For the clearest and most formal sounding, I would go with "Reduction of Association Rules". If some description of the specific type of association is useful: "Reduction of [insert adjective here] Association Rules".